# How to change this arrow function in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I need to change this arrow function to a regular function on the line of my return toto but i don't really understand how, here is the code :

```
class Ratchet extends APlugin<CentralizerConfigPluginRatchet> {
  public search = (): Promise<CentralizerNotif[]> => {throw Error("Not implemented");};

  public notif =
  (): Promise<CentralizerNotif[]> => {
    const toto = new RatchetLib.RatchetAPI(this.config.baseurl);
    return toto.getAsset({validation: true}).then(result => {
      return [{
        name: `You ${result.assets.length} things to moderate `,
        link: "https://www.exemple.com",
      }];
    });
  };
}
```

Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable ?

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason as to why you would need to change it to a keyword function. But if you wan't to you just have to remove the `=` and the `=>`:

```
class Ratchet extends APlugin<CentralizerConfigPluginRatchet> {
  public search(): Promise<CentralizerNotif[]> {
    throw Error("Not implemented");
  }

  public notif(): Promise<CentralizerNotif[]> {
    const toto = new RatchetLib.RatchetAPI(this.config.baseurl);
    return toto.getAsset({validation: true}).then(result => {
      return [{
        name: `You ${result.assets.length} things to moderate `,
        link: "https://www.exemple.com",
      }];
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Actually I was talking about the .then(result => {

Answer (score 0):

Changing an anonymous arrow callback function into a regular function is straightforward. In your case,

```js
return toto.getAsset({validation: true}).then(result => {
  /* ... */
});
```

will become

```js
return toto.getAsset({validation: true}).then(function (result) {
  /* ... */
});
```

You can also choose to have a named function here:

```js
return toto.getAsset({validation: true}).then(function myCustomFunc(result) {
  /* ... */
});
```

Keep in mind that arrow functions and function declarations (using the `function` keyword) have some [differences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to take note of.